# How to using a file as input to program starting from specific line in command?

Tags: command-line, bash, input

To use a file as input for program, the `<` operator can be used.

For example,

```
xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < input.txt
```

However, is there a command to specify if I don't want to use the whole file, but only take some lines as input?

Some like，

```
xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < input.txt --starting_line=100 --ending_line=120
```

(This surely won't work, just want to know if there are option like that)

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` or another tool to filter out the specific line and pipe it to the command. For example, the following will send only the 10th and 13th lines of the file to `xmacroplay`:

```
sed -n '10p; 13p' input.txt | xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" --starting_line=100 --ending_line=120
```

Or in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 10 || NR == 13' input.txt | xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" --starting_line=100 --ending_line=120
```

If, for some reason, you cannot use a pipe, use process substitution:

```
xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" --starting_line=100 --ending_line=120 < <(sed -n '10p; 13p' input.txt)
```